# What is CS GO noclip command?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Im using a dust2 modified map to better my aim and smokes, but i need the noclip command to move faster for the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you need

```
sv_cheats 1
```

This requires running a local server or have rcon access to the server. ***WARNING: THIS WILL ENABLE FOR ALL PLAYERS***

```
noclip
```

It's really that simple. You can also use Иво Недев's answer and do

```
bind (key) noclip
```

[Noclip VDC page](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Noclip)

[Bind VDC page.](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Bind)

Answer (score 5):

First you need to enter `sv_cheats 1` into the console, to be able to use the noclip command.
Then you can either just type "noclip" on the console or bind it to a key like so: (again in the console)

> bind M noclip

pressing M will enable you to fly trough walls, pressing it again will disable the noclip function.

Not sure if you're using vanilla dust, but there are some GREAT dust_2 smoke practice maps in the workshop, look for them, they have pictures and explanations and exact spots where to stand and where to look, and they have them for most other maps too.

For aim I'd suggest getting a practice map, there are quite a few nice ones out there.

Comment: Im using a workshop map with explanations but for my comodity i need the noclip command, thanks.